# In Joomla Category Blog Layout With jSeblod CCK - Where does $this->category->description get its layout?

Tags: php, templates, joomla1.5, cck, categories

I am trying alter the way Joomla displays the list of sub categories in the category blog layout. Yet i cannot find a template file anywhere that formats these listings. In every template where these listings are located i find:

```
$this->category->description
```

Where is this pulling its formatting and data from?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also forgot to mention that i am using jSeblod CCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it exactly where it should have been. In the jSeblod CCK categories_subcategories content template:

/templates/categories_subcategories/index.php